# identity_matrix/zero_matrix: do they allocate?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-ublas

matrix classes `identity_matrix` and `zero_matrix` are templates with `ALLOC` as a second parameter. But do they really allocate memory?

Comment: Have a look at online doc.: [boost::numeric::ublas::identity_matrix< T, ALLOC > Class Template Reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/html/classboost_1_1numeric_1_1ublas_1_1identity__matrix.html#_details): _ALLOC  an allocator for storing the zeros and one elements. **By default, a standar allocator is used.**_ (Sorry, for the typo. I cited by copy/paste. Emphasizing by me.)

Comment: @Scheff, well, I looked in the code, but didn't find out why `ALLOC` is paramethrized as it is not used.

Comment: I remember that once somebody told me: "Source code is the only true documentation." (and didn't write any comments in the sources/headers...) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't allocate memory, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/boostorg/ublas/blob/develop/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp#L3429)  and [here](https://github.com/boostorg/ublas/blob/develop/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp#L3905). I think the documentation is misleading: allocators are not used for initialization of static [`zero_`](https://github.com/boostorg/ublas/blob/develop/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp#L3892) or [`one_`](https://github.com/boostorg/ublas/blob/develop/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp#L3439) elements, just the constuctors of the type `T`:

```
template<class T, class ALLOC>
const typename zero_matrix<T, ALLOC>::value_type zero_matrix<T, ALLOC>::zero_ = T(/*zero*/);

...
template<class T, class ALLOC>
const typename identity_matrix<T, ALLOC>::value_type identity_matrix<T, ALLOC>::zero_ = T(/*zero*/);
template<class T, class ALLOC>
const typename identity_matrix<T, ALLOC>::value_type identity_matrix<T, ALLOC>::one_ (1); // ISSUE: need 'one'-traits here
```

However, the typedefs `size_type` and `difference_type` are part of the public interface and in order to be consistent, `ALLOC::size_type` and `ALLOC::difference_type` are used (instead of the "usual" `std::size_t` and `std::ptrdiff_t`). This was done with the following [change](https://github.com/boostorg/ublas/commit/e3447528bb9716a6909d607c82045e1273d2c2d7#diff-2de82cdec08e2daafffe0fc167d425a1L1981).

Comment: so, `ALLOC` is only used for `size_type` and `difference_type`, but not for allocations. Thank you, thats what I was looking for